# Bat to rename folder adding an incremental number

Tags: batch-file, directory, rename

I have path with more folders inside.

I need to rename ONLY the folders that contains name "Palemoon Portable Openvpn" adding an incremental number too.

Path that contains the folders (warings contains spaces)

```
D:\Programmi Installati
```

Inside I have more folder with this name

```
Palemoon Portable Openvpn 1 - Copia
Palemoon Portable Openvpn 1 - Copia (2)
Palemoon Portable Openvpn 1 - Copia (3)
Palemoon Portable Openvpn 1 - Copia (4)
Palemoon Portable Openvpn 1 - Copia (5)
Palemoon Portable Openvpn 1 - Copia (50)
Palemoon Portable Openvpn 1 - Copia (60)
Palemoon Portable Openvpn 1 - Copia (100)
Palemoon Portable Openvpn 1 - Copia (150)
Palemoon Portable Openvpn 1 - Copia (300)
```

I need to rename folder that contains name "Palemoon Portable Openvpn" in:

```
Palemoon Portable Openvpn 1
Palemoon Portable Openvpn 2
Palemoon Portable Openvpn 3
Palemoon Portable Openvpn 4
Palemoon Portable Openvpn 5
Palemoon Portable Openvpn 6
Palemoon Portable Openvpn 7
Palemoon Portable Openvpn 8
Palemoon Portable Openvpn 9
Palemoon Portable Openvpn 10
```

The folder name fix is "Palemoon Portable Openvpn" I need to rename only the folders that contains in name "Palemoon Portable Openvpn".

WARNING: The path with the folders have spaces "D:\Programmi Installati"

Thanks

Comment: 1.) have you tried anything on your own? please provide your code (note SO is not a coding service platform!); 2.) is the sort order of the original folders relevant?

Comment: 1) I was unable to create a bat to rename because I can not specify to only rename folders concerned (folders that name contains Palemoon Portable Openvpn only) and not any other. 2) order does not matter, I'm interested in all the folders are renamed indicating a sequential number increasing.

Comment: Is sort order really unimportant?  Can the `Copia (300)` folder be number 2 for example?

Comment: @foxidrive Yes in "copia (300)" you can assign number 2 or different number, I need this bat to rename the folder (all folder contains same files) there is not important the order it's important have the folder name with incremental numbers..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this - remove the `echo` keyword if what you see on the console is correct.

You will need write permissions in the `D:\Programmi Installati` folder.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set counter=
for /d %%a in ("D:\Programmi Installati\Palemoon Portable Openvpn*") do (
   set /a counter+=1
   echo ren "%%~fa" "Palemoon Portable Openvpn !counter!"
)
pause
```

Comment: Working Great Thanks !